# What does "Memory of 128K by 9" means?

Tags: memory-hardware

This is probably a very stupid question but I couldn't find an answer anywhere. I'm reading the Technical Reference book of the IBM PC XT and it says that "**The system board also has from 128K by 9 to 256K by 9 of R/W memory.**" What does this by 9 means?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I strongly suspect that this is referring to [parity RAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM_parity).

Comment: For error detection/correction, there is a reason to ***not*** want more than 1 bit evaluated "by the same primitive" to reside in any given device.